# accessibility between projects question

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 library projects: AProject and BProject and one web project: WebProject.
AProject has a class:

```
public class WorkerManager {
    public Worker Get(long workerId) {
        ....
        ....
    }

    public Worker Get(Guid companyId, long workerId) {
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

I would like classes from BProject to be able to use the first version of the Worker Get:

```
WorkerManager  a=new WorkerManager ();
a.Get(8);
```

And I would like this method to be hidden for the web project.

If I make the `Worker Get(long workerId)` internal, then BProject will not be able to use this method, and if I make it public the web project gets access to this method.

How can I prevent access to the web project and allow access to the BProject?

Comment: Using interfaces will help you separate your concerns

Comment: @IAbstract: Can you give an example?

Comment: If this was VB.NET instead of C#, you could use the [Friend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08w05ey2.aspx) keyword in VB.NET

Comment: @icemanid, it seems that's exactly the same as C#'s `internal`.

Comment: There are solutions for this, you are shooting them all down.  Why is it so important that the web project doesn't use an assembly?  It you don't want to use an assembly then just don't add a reference to it.  That's not complicated.  If this is some kind of convoluted licensing scheme then buy the protection your are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need [Friend Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0tke9fxk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

They basically allow you to make your class internal, but specify that `BProject` should have access to the internal classes of `AProject`.

#### Update

I've never actually had to use Friend Assemblies, so I won't be able to give you any better direction than Google can.

Other people have mentioned using interfaces, and I agree that this is generally a good approach. Whether or not it works for you will depend on the structure of your code, though. Let's say you move the `WorkerManager` class to a new Project (C). Project C depends on Project B. Project A depends on both C and B. WebProject depends on A and B.

```
         /-------------\
WebProject -> A -> C -> B
               \-------/
```

Project B now defines an interface like the following:

```
public interface IWorkerManager 
{
    public Worker Get(long workerId);
}
```

And WorkerManager in Project C implements the interface:

```
public class WorkerManager : IWorkerManager {...}
```

Now Project A can produce `IWorkerManager`s via a factory, so your Web Project never has to say `new WorkerManager()`.

```
public class WorkerManagerFactory
{
    public IWorkerManager Get() {return new WorkerManager();}
}
```

Now it's still possible for Project A to access the other methods:

```
new WorkerManager().Get(compGuid, workerId);
```

... but Web Project can only access what's been defined by the interface:

```
new WorkerManagerFactory().Get().Get(workerId);
```

This illustrates one way that you might achieve what you're looking for. You could find better solutions by leveraging Dependency Injection, but this explanation is getting well beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: It looks very complicated. It sais "you must explicitly specify the name of the output file". How do I know which name to give to BProject assembly?..

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`InternalsVisibleTo` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) and make the method `internal`.

But I'm not sure it's a good design, hiding methods this way. If it's just an implementation detail, it should be private. If it's part of public surface of the class, it should be public to everyone. There's not much space in between that (ignoring derived classes and protected members).

One situation where this can be useful is unit-testing private functionality. There are probably other uses, but they should be pretty rare.

Comment: AProject and BProject are part of my domain and the web is part of the presentation. I would like the programmers of the presentations part will supply companyId and use only with "Worker Get(Guid companyId, long workerId)" where other domain projects will be able to get directly the worker without passing the companyId variable (since doing so will force me to pass this variable throw each function of the functions stuck).